# Minha requisição HTTP(GET) não está executando no ngOnInit() - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, http-request

Eu tenho um CRUD no angular 6 que faz conexão com o node e mysql.
Quando eu acesso a página inicial a função getQuotes() carrega todos os dados que necessito.
Quando eu acesso a tela de atualizar um registro e realizo está atualização sou encaminhado para a tela inicial, mas o valor que aparece ainda é o antigo. Só quando eu aperto F5 e recarrega a página que o valor atualizado é buscado.

Como arrumo isso?

```
component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Quote } from '../../1-model/quote.model';
import { QuoteService } from '../../quote.service';
import * as $ from 'jquery'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quotes-abertas',
  templateUrl: './quotes-abertas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quotes-abertas.component.css']
})
export class QuotesAbertasComponent implements OnInit {

  public quotes: Quote[];
  public daysInLine: Date = new Date();

  constructor(private quoteService: QuoteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {      
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#pesquisar").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#quote-table tr").filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });

    this.getQuotes()
  }

  getQuotes() {
    return this.quoteService.getQuotes()
      .subscribe(
        quotes => {
          console.log(quotes);
          this.quotes = quotes
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Abaixo segue o código de update!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuoteService } from '../../quote.service';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { QuoteValue } from '../../1-model/QuoteValue.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-quotes-abertas-detalhes',
  templateUrl: './quotes-abertas-detalhes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quotes-abertas-detalhes.component.css']
})
export class QuotesAbertasDetalhesComponent implements OnInit {

  public quoteValue: Observable<QuoteValue>;
  public detailsForm: FormGroup;
  public quote: QuoteValue

  constructor(
    private quoteService: QuoteService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private route: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id = + this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.quoteService.getQuote(id)
      .subscribe(
        quote => {
          this.quote = quote
        }
      );

    this.quoteValue = this.quoteService.getQuote(id)
      .pipe(
        tap(quoteValue => this.detailsForm.patchValue(quoteValue))
      )

    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [id],
      QuoteType: [null],
      AccountOwner: [null, Validators.required],
      AccountContactName: [null, Validators.required],
      AccountContactEmail: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      AccountContactTel: [null, Validators.required],
      AccountNumber: [null, Validators.required],
      IdOportunity: [null, Validators.required],
      IBX: [null, Validators.required],
      ProjectStatus: ['In Progress', Validators.required],
      InitialTerm: [0, [Validators.max(60), Validators.min(1)]],
      RenewalTerm: [0, [Validators.max(60), Validators.min(1)]],
      PriceIncrease: [null],
      EffectiveDate: [null],
      NonStandardTerm: [null],
      FreeMonths: [0],
      RampMonths: [0],
      RampPerCent: [null],
      RampStartDate: [null],
      RampEndDate: [null],
    })
  }

  update(): void {
    const updateQuote = this.detailsForm.getRawValue() as QuoteValue
    this.quoteService.updateQuote(updateQuote).subscribe()
    this.goBack()
  }

  delete(): void {
    this.quoteService.deleteQuote(this.quote.id).subscribe();
    this.goBack()
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.route.navigate(['homepage', 'quotes-abertas'])
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];` já tentou assim?

Comment: O problema é depois que eu faço a atualização e sou redirecionado para a tela inicial.
Lá o valor que eu modifiquei não foi alterado e só depois que eu dou um F5 que o valor novo é recarregado.

Acho que tem algo errado com a minha requisição no ngOnInit da tela inicial

Comment: então acho que esta faltando vc busca esses valores na sua tela inicial... no ngint ou contructor

Comment: pelo que vc fala ele ta buscando pela url... entao quando vc direciona pra la ele n tem um comando de return no valor novo que ele foi alimentado

Comment: E como eu resolvo isso mano? Quando eu clico em update... um modal surge e pergunta se eu desejo realmente fazer aquela alteração. Se eu apertar confirm sou redirecionado para a tela inicial.
Estou usando o this.route.navigate([''])